# Realizar upload de arquivo com parâmetros no Silex com Angular-File-Upload

Tags: angularjs, upload, angularjs-directives, file-upload, silex

estou fazendo um trabalho com Angular (versão 1.5.8) e usando o Silex como Web Service. Para enviar o arquivo para o Web Service estou utilizando o Angular-File-Upload (versão 1.5.1) , e meu service Angular esta assim:

```js
self.salvarAnexo = function (id, descricao, anexo) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/salvar-anexo";

    $upload.upload({
        url: url,
        data: {
            id: id,
            descricao: descricao,
        },

        file: anexo
    }).then(function (response) {

        deferred.resolve(response);

    }, function (error) {
        deferred.reject(error);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

E o Web Service esta assim:

```php
    $this->controllers->post('/salvar-anexo', function (Application $app, Request $request) {

        $file = $request->files->get('file');

        if($file){
            $file->move(__DIR__ . '/../../../temp', $file->getClientOriginalName());
        }

        //$params = $request->request->all();

        var_dump($request->files);
        exit;
```

Eu recebo normalmente o arquivo, consigo mover ele para o local que preciso, mas os parâmetros que estou enviando no objeto **data** eu não estou conseguindo receber no meu Web Service.

Será que alguém poderia me ajudar???
Vlw Galera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução que achei foi buscar os dados via variável de ambiente $_POST, não achei muito certo por estar usando um framework, mas foi o que funcionou.

Answer (score 2):

Código angular-file-upload. Omita o atributo `file` e adicione no objeto `data`.

```
$upload.upload({
    url: url,
    data: {
        id: id,
        descricao: descricao,
        file: anexo
    },
}).then(function (response) {
    deferred.resolve(response);
}, function (error) {
    deferred.reject(error);
});
```

Comment: vou testar dessa forma.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei como esta o restante do seu código, mas coloca um

```
echo $request->files
```

e veja se recebe.

Comment: Tentei "debugar" deste jeito mas por algum motivo o framework apaga qualquer parâmetro que é passado junto com o arquivo